# calling openlog before every syslog C++

Tags: c++, c, syslog

I have created my own C library which my co-workers intend to use. In this wrapper, I intend to use `syslog` and depending on an input parameter, I wish to switch between `LOCAL0` and `LOCAL1`.

The easiest way I found is to do `openlog()` with `LOCAL0` or `LOCAL1`, depending on an input param, and then do `syslog()` and `closelog().

I have all 3 in the same wrapper API (something simliar to below):

```
void syslog_wrap_api(int flag, const char *msg)
{
setlogmask(LOG_UPTO (LOG_INFO));
if(flag == 0)
    openlog("myapplog",LOG_NDELAY,LOG_LOCAL0);
else
    openlog("myapplog",LOG_NDELAY,LOG_LOCAL1);
syslog(LOG_INFO,"%s",msg);
closelog()
}
```

My question is, can this API cause problems under stress (performance issues)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is, in my opinion, the wrong way to go about it, but the documentation is confusing.

Whether you have problems under stress is going to be be determined by the implementation of `openlog` in your C library. It might well be problematic. More to the point, in a multithreaded environment, one thread may issue the `syslog` after another thread issues the `openlog`, meaning the wrong priority is used.

The key to how to do this right is in the man page:

> The facility argument establishes a default to be used if none is specified in subsequent calls to `syslog()`. Values for option and facility are given below ... The `priority` argument is formed by OR-ing the `facility` and the `level` values (explained below).

The clue as to how to exploit this is here:

> The use of `openlog()` is optional; it will automatically be called by `syslog()` if necessary, in which case `ident` will default to `NULL`.

If you don't use `openlog`, there must be some way of expressing the `facility`. The answer is that you can specify the facility as zero to `openlog` (or not use it at all), and OR in the facility to the `priority` argument of `syslog`.

So, something like:

```
syslog(LOG_INFO | (flag?LOG_LOCAL1:LOG_LOCAL0),"%s",msg);
```

Comment: Great! It works, Thanks :) ! Just a followup question though, can I also manage to have individual "identities" (program_name) without using openlog() everytime ? I mean, if I also want to have different identity along with different facility according to the "flag" ? Do you think it is possible in some way ?

Comment: Simply put the identity in the string you log (rather than use the `identity` argument of `openlog`)

Comment: yeah sure..thanks, that works..i m also remote logging, so i needed to make sure in my syslog config to get the RAW message, only then the first string is considered program name at remote. well, now i seem to have got rid of openlog()...